# How to create nested column with tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind to create a 12 column grid layout.

I want to create a nested 3/12 column in `grid-child` which equal width with `col-span-3` at parent `grid-parent`.

I created another grid but 3/12 column this `grid-child` is small than `grid-parent`. I mean width of 12 column of `grid-child` == 9 column of `grid-parent`.

If I remove the div `grid-child` then `col-span-3` doesn't work.

So how can I deal with this?

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container w-full grid grid-cols-12 mx-auto grid-parent">
  <div class="col-span-3 bg-blue-500 h-screen"></div>
  <div class="col-span-9 h-screen bg-red-500">
    <div class="grid grid-cols-12 grid-child">
      <div class="col-span-3 bg-purple-500 h-20"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use `grid-cols-12` in `grid-child`, because you took 3 cols out of 12 cols, then the right-hand side has only 9 cols left. Therefore, 12 cols of 9 cols are not equal to the original 12 cols.

[image]